# Read matrix row by row from huge compressed file

Tags: python, numpy, io, large-files

I want to read rows of a large matrix. I don't need random access, so `h5py` might be a bit of an overkill and might be a lot slower than sequential reading. The faster option would be `mmap`, but from what I understand, I can't use compressed files for that.

So I guess I would just need to read chunks from a binary file. How should I prepare the matrix? It would definitely need to be a binary file (not csv), but I was wondering if I can write numpy arrays conveniently? Unfortunately I'm pretty sure I can't use pickle as my matrix will be huge (around 40GB before compression).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like `bz2.BZ2Compressor` may help do what you want.